# Beyond the horizon - mathematics with three signs

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, logic, arithmetic

Instead of having two signs $\{+,-\}$ consider mathematics with **three** $\{r,g,b\}$. It is $$(r)x + (g)x + (b)x = 0, \ x\in(0,\infty).\tag{1}$$
where $$0= (r)0 = (g)0 = (b)0,$$
is the additive zero-element. It holds
$$(r)x + (g)y + (b)z = \text{sign}(\max(x,y,z))[\max(x,y,z) - \text{mid}(x,y,z)].\tag{2}$$
Multiplication is given by the table below.

[image]

Smaller-than relation still denoted by $<$ is clock-wise
$$(r)x < (g)x < (b)x < (r)x < ...$$
giving the following number line.

[image]

What are the differences to usual mathematics/analysis?
Is that approach consistent? What about applicability?
I am prob. not the first having this idea...

**Edit:** In contrast to usual analysis,

- addition is not associative
- $<$ is not transitive
- there is no $\max$ or $\min$ among three different signs
- every number has one unique $n$-th root
- $x+y=0$, $x$ fixed, has two solutions
- every integer has two successors and two predecessors
- a successor is also a predecessor of the same number

It looks (1) does not work. Better use
$$(r)x + (g)x = (g)x + (b)x = (r)x + (b)x= 0.$$

An example for addition:

[image]

Comment: Looks self-contradictory to me. If $(r)x<(g)x<(b)x<(r)x,$ then $(r)x<(r)x;$ isn't that a contradiction? Or is the $<$ symbol not transitive any more? That would be odd! Or did you merely mean to use $(r)x\le(g)x\le(b)x\le(r)x?$

Comment: Its not transitive anymore among different signs.

Comment: How do you define  addition, for example $(r)1+(g)2$ ?

Comment: Since $(r) < (g)$ its $(g)1$.

Comment: It's still not clear how addition is defined. What is $(r)1+(g)1$? It looks like it's $0$? But then $(r)1+(g)1+(b)1=0$ so $(b)1=0$?

Comment: Could you also provide a proof that every number has a unique square root? It might help people understand how everything should be defined

Comment: This can be seen by the diagonal elements in the multiplication table.

Comment: Your example is indeed a problem, since $(r)1+(g)1 = 0$.

Comment: I think additivity is not associative anymore.

Comment: Your new suggestion gives $(r)1=(r)1+(g)1+(b)1=(b)1$. Keep trying though, trying stuff like this can lead to new maths and finding problems is excellent practice for working in algebra

Comment: You might want to (if you haven't already) look into the complex roots of unity, $u_n^k=\exp(\frac kn2\pi i)$, in particular with $n=3$.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain No, only when you assume associativity.

Comment: @mr_e_man The thing is there is no $i$ here.

Comment: Do you have an explicit question which you want answered? Open-ended questions like "What can be said about (...)" are often not on-topic here, unless they are narrowed down significantly (implicitly or explicitly).

Comment: Thanks, I have specified that.

Comment: If you don't have associativity then you need to put a lot of brackets in - Your example could be $(r)3+\left(\left((g)5+(b)3\right)+(r)3\right)=(r)4$

Comment: Absolutely right, I used a successive order from left.

Comment: Why did you choose  this particular multiplication table? This way you don't have a 1-element.

Comment: It looked symmetric to me. Exchanging $b$ and $g$ inside the table makes $r$ the $1$ element. Might work better.

Comment: @fwgb , in order to cover the plane, you could use two variables, but the second rotated 60 degrees respect to the first one. Other thing would be to understand and develop  the successor function in depth, after that, you can derive addition and multiplication. I  think that as non-isomorphic to the complex make them more original, even if loose some algebraic properties

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to define the addition and multiplication is the following 
$$
G=\{(\alpha, x)|\alpha\in \mathbb{N}_3, x\in\mathbb{R}^+\}\\
(\alpha)x:=(\alpha,x)\\
(\alpha)x+(\beta)y=\begin{cases}
(\alpha)x+y,&\alpha=\beta\\
 (\alpha)x-y,&\alpha\neq\beta, x>y\\ 
 (\beta)y-x,& \alpha\neq\beta, y>x
\end{cases}\\
(\alpha)x\cdot(\beta)y=(\alpha+\beta)x\cdot y$$

Comment: Addition is a special case for two of my original suggestion. Is $(\alpha +\beta)$ modulo 3?

Comment: How is it a special case? I went by the example you gave. Yes the addition is in the sense of the residue group modulo 3.

Comment: It can be rewritten as $\text{sign}(\max(x,y))[\max(x,y)-\min(x,y)]$.

Comment: If that is your definition of the addition, then $(\alpha)x+(\alpha)x=0$. I don't think that is your intention?

Comment: Right, I forgot about this case.

Comment: Furthermore, you should(!) define the operation only for two (arbitrary) elements since it is a binary operation. Especially if it's not associative. To be honest I did not even realise that you were trying to define the operation at that line in the original post.

Comment: Correct, that was before we found out that we have no associativity. Your formula is what I had in mind. You may add a mult. table. Thanks.